# D3: Timeline with smooth curves and varying thickness

Tags: d3.js

I am working on an experimental audio player interface. I have multiple timelines (in this example, two). Fragments of these timelines form a new combined timeline.

The coordinates of the points A–H are given. What I am looking for:

- How do I create a shape with smooth curves when the "floor" (as in a floor in a builing) changes from the normal timeline to the combined timeline? (The curve between A and B, vor example.
- Can D3 help me in creating the shapes with varying thickness (thinner on the normal timelines, thicker on the combined timelines)? For instance, is there a helper that I can pass a single path to and data on the thickness at each point and it creates a shape from it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be reproduced with an [area generator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#area), you don't pass the thickness you would set a `y0` for the bottom line which is simply `y - thickness`.  The *smoothness* can be produced by using a spline or monotone [interpolation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#area_interpolate).